# How to support 2 types of callback in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird, intercom

In the `intercom-client` github I see this code:

> ```
> client.users.list(function (d) {
>   // d is the response from the server
> });
>
> // Or
>
> client.users.list(function (err, d) {
>   // err is an error response object, or null
>   // d is a successful response object, or null
> });
> ```

My question is: How `intercom` know if I pass `funcrtion(err,d)` or just `function(data)`.

I check the source code and found that they use `bluebird` library. How bluebird does it?

I want that my function will do the same.

**In other words:**

```
function myFunction(data,callback){
  if (callbackListenToErrArgument(callback)) 
       callback(null,data)
   else
       callback(data)

}
```

How to implement `callbackListenToErrArgument` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can inspect the `.length` property on the function getting passed. The `.length` property is the number of arguments defined for the function.

```
function hasErrorArgument(callback) {
  if (callback.length < 2) { return false; } // Has 1 or 0.
  else return true; // has 2 or more
} // Yes, I know it can be reduced to one line. Sue me.
```

Please note: This is bad practice. You should provide a uniform signature to the callbacks you accept. `(err, data) => {}` is a good signature to follow.

Or even better, have your `list()` function return a **[`Promise`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/promise)** object: (Promises are natively supported only in some browsers. Check compatibility before use, or use a polyfill or a library).

```
client.users.list()
  .then(listOfUsers => {
    // Use data here
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Handle errors here
  });
```

Comment: Thank's. Please explain this: `(err, data) => {}`
Is `(function(){}).length` works in most of the browsers? Is this something new? Do you know about IE6?

Comment: `(err, data) => {}` is the ES6 equivalent to `function(err, data) {}`. `fn.length` existed as long as I can remember, and if you still need IE6 support, may God Have Mercy Upon Your Soul.

Comment: IE6, is a way of asking if this is in the fundamentals of JavaScript, or this is came from the revolutions... I'm not asking about IE5.5, who don't supports `bind`, and `call`...

Comment: `fn.length` is supported everywhere. The `()=>{}` syntax is not (but is with Babel).

Comment: …and returning promises is an even better practice.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, that's true. Depends on browser support and your willingness to transpile (i.e. legacy project etc).

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that looking at the method length:

```
fun=function(a,b,c) {
  console.log(a,b,c)
}
(a,b,c) {
  console.log(a,b,c)
}
fun.prototype.constructor.length
3
```

could be considered a bad practice, as stated by @madara-uchiha, the `bluebird` library has a method caller function that is:

```
var makeMethodCaller = function (methodName) {
    return new Function("ensureMethod", "                                    \n\
        return function(obj) {                                               \n\
            'use strict'                                                     \n\
            var len = this.length;                                           \n\
            ensureMethod(obj, 'methodName');                                 \n\
            switch(len) {                                                    \n\
                case 1: return obj.methodName(this[0]);                      \n\
                case 2: return obj.methodName(this[0], this[1]);             \n\
                case 3: return obj.methodName(this[0], this[1], this[2]);    \n\
                case 0: return obj.methodName();                             \n\
                default:                                                     \n\
                    return obj.methodName.apply(obj, this);                  \n\
            }                                                                \n\
        };                                                                   \n\
        ".replace(/methodName/g, methodName))(ensureMethod);
};
```

**[UPDATE]**
I have added a working snippet of the Bluebird code to discuss it. As someone stated this seems to be applied to something else, even if there is a method length guard in the switch case. Check the code:

```js
var console={}
console.log=function(msgs) { document.writeln(msgs)};

var makeMethodCaller = function (methodName) {
    return new Function("ensureMethod", "                                    \n\
        return function(obj) {                                               \n\
            var len = this.length;                                           \n\
            console.log(\"Who is this\"+this);                                           \n\
            ensureMethod(obj, 'methodName');                                 \n\
            switch(len) {                                                    \n\
                case 1: return obj.methodName(this[0]);                      \n\
                case 2: return obj.methodName(this[0], this[1]);             \n\
                case 3: return obj.methodName(this[0], this[1], this[2]);    \n\
                case 0: return obj.methodName();                             \n\
                default:                                                     \n\
                    return obj.methodName.apply(obj, this);                  \n\
            }                                                                \n\
        };                                                                   \n\
        ".replace(/methodName/g, methodName))(ensureMethod);
};
function ensureMethod(obj, methodName) {
    var fn;
    if (obj != null) fn = obj[methodName];
    if (typeof fn !== "function") {
        var message = "Object " + JSON.stringify(obj) + " has no method '" +
            JSON.stringify(methodName) + "'";
        throw new Error(message);
    }
    return fn;
}
var fn=makeMethodCaller("callMe");


console.log(fn)

var obj0= {
 callMe : function() { console.log("\n\n\ncalled with 0 params")}
};
var obj1= {
 callMe : function(a) { console.log("\n\n\ncalled with 1 params")}
};
var obj2= {
 callMe : function(a,b) { console.log("\n\n\ncalled 2 params")}
};
var obj3= {
 callMe : function(a,b,c) { console.log("\n\n\ncalled 3 params")}
};


[obj0,obj1,obj2,obj3].map(function(e) { 
  return fn( e );
});
```

Comment: Why it is bad-prartice, and why you'r method is better? what are you doing there? why to create new function this way `new Function()`?

Comment: @Amina Sorry I clarify. Bluebird method does exactly the same of checking the length. Look at the `switch case` there. It checks the function arguments length and the select the right assert... I do not argument why is bad, just realized that `bluebird` use that solution ;)

Comment: @loretoparisi: I'm pretty sure that `this` is not a function however in the code you cited, but rather an array.

Comment: Btw, `fun.prototype.constructor === fun`

Comment: @Bergi yes of course it is, but it was to show that under the hood this is what happens ;). The code from bluebird is here: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/src/call_get.js ahd and you can clearly see how it is used: ```var makeMethodCaller = function (methodName) {
… 
61     return getCompiled(name, makeMethodCaller, callerCache);
62 };
63 
64 getGetter = function(name) {
65     return getCompiled(name, makeGetter, getterCache);```

Comment: @loretoparisi: I can clearly see that it is *not* used to distinguish callbacks with different numbers of parameters.

Comment: @Bergi yes I have checked the code and added a snippet above, not sure in node context, but here `this` refers to the `Window`, so in `node` it should refers to the calling process/function I guess.

Comment: As I said, they are called on an array. Those "methodCaller" functions are just over-optimised versions of [this simple method](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/src/call_get.js#L80) (sans the method name being passed as the last array element)

Comment: @Bergi that said, which would be a solution different than `switch( function.length) {...}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102976/discussion-between-loretoparisi-and-bergi).